# Mover o maior valor de um Array para o final do mesmo.

Tags: java, array

Preciso criar um método que pegue o maior valor de um Array e passe-o para o final desse mesmo Array, de forma que o array fique ordenado, sem perder nenhum valor.
Tentei de diversas maneiras e ainda não consegui. Por favor corrijam meu código.

Meu código:

```
public static void deslocaMaiorFinal(int[] Arranjo){
    int maior = Arranjo[0];
    int aux;
    for(int c = 1; c < Arranjo.length; c++){
        if(Arranjo[c] > maior) maior = Arranjo[c];
    }//end for

    for(int c = (Arranjo.length - 1); c >= 0; c--){
        if(Arranjo[Arranjo.length-1] != maior){
            aux = Arranjo[c];
            Arranjo[c] = maior;
            Arranjo[c-1] = aux;
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return;
}//end method
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa da segunda parte:

```
for(int c = (Arranjo.length - 1); c >= 0; c--){
   if(Arranjo[Arranjo.length-1] != maior){
       aux = Arranjo[c];
       Arranjo[c] = maior;
       Arranjo[c-1] = aux;
   }//end if
}//end for
```

Se você já identificou o maior valor (como fez na primeira parte) basta atribuir para a última posição.

```
Arranjo[Arranjo.length-1] = maior;
```

Comment: Agora, se você quer ordenar o array, aí é outra coisa.

Comment: Sim, eu quero ordenar de forma que o maior fique em último.